# Where do all these rows come from when making a distributed matrix in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given a Spark DataFrame with a column of id's and a column of normalized feature vectors:

```
df.select("id", "norm")
res247: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: double, norm: vector]

df.count()
res150: Long = 3445
```

I want to convert the feature vectors to a distributed matrix. I will use the id column and the vectors to generate an IndexedRowMatrix

```
def transfunc(r: Row) = {new IndexedRow(r.getAs[Double](0).toLong,
                                        r.getAs[SparseVector](1))
}
val irm = new IndexedRowMatrix(tfidf_df.select("id", "norm").rdd.map(transfunc))

transfunc: (r: org.apache.spark.sql.Row)org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRow
irm: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRowMatrix = org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRowMatrix@51cdf498
```

The distributed matrix `irm` should have 3445 rows, since the original dataframe had that many rows. But

```
irm.numRows()
irm.numCols()

res248: Long = 205853916197
res249: Long = 262144
```

The number of columns is right, but the number of rows is....large. Where did all these extra rows come from?

Comment: What is the largest id in your dataframe? 205853916197?